# python with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to make matrix with unknown numbers, and instead of showing it as matrix its saying Matrix and than putting all in 1 line.

```py
Matrix([[cos(t2(t)), 0, sin(t2(t)), 0], [sin(t2(t)), 0, -cos(t2(t)), 0], [0, 1, 0, d2(t)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

In the pic you can see its showing the matrix in 1 line. this is my good for the matrix and the printing

```py
import sympy as sm
import numpy as np
from sympy.physics.vector import init_vprinting
init_vprinting(use_latex='mathjax', prettyprint=False)
from sympy.physics.mechanics import dynamicsymbols
from sympy import symbols

theta1, theta2, theta4, theta5, theta6, d2, d3, d6 = dynamicsymbols('t1 t2 t4 t5 t6 d2 d3 d6')
theta = dynamicsymbols('theta')

A12=sm.Array([[sm.cos(theta2),0,sm.sin(theta2),0], [sm.sin(theta2),0,-sm.cos(theta2),0],[0,1,0,d2],[0,0,0,1]])

print(A12)
```

I tried using array but it did not work, still was in 1 line. using 6 matrix and need to double the, together in the end so for now trying to make 1 look right

Comment: _"still was in 1 line. using 6 matrix and need to double the, together in the end so for now trying to make 1 look right"_, I don't think that anyone here will be able to understand this, and as a result, this question is nearly impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "one line matrix" is a compact method of representing the matrix. It is the form given by the "str" function (which apparently is the default method of printing in your context). By using `init_printing()` at the outset you will get better looking output (probably); I rarely use it.

[sample IDE session showing different printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpXzA.png)

Note, too, that you are using an `Array` instead of a `Matrix`. You can pass your Array as the argument to Matrix and have it do the right thing.

Comment: by mistake sent pic using array
but still showing the same with matrix and array
and tried printing with init_printing() and it printed nothing

Comment: fixed it now
found function pprint